# Android app for broadcast message to multiple devices from pc

Tags: android, client-server, message

I need to create an application to send messages from my computer to the android devices. 
The message has to be send to all the devices installed my app.

If possible to create the app pl z give me ideas.

Comment: that is called Push Notifications http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use Google Cloud Messaging Service. Google Cloud Messaging GCM is a free service that helps developers to send notifications to their Android application. GCM connection servers take messages from a 3rd-party application server (written by you) and send them to a GCM-enabled Android application (the "client app," also written by you) running on a device.
This is [Google Official site](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html) for you. This is [sample tutorial site](http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-tutorial/) for you.